# Are gentiles forbidden from consuming blood?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, noachide-laws, blood

The seven noachide laws prohibit eating the limb of a live animal and spilling the blood of another human being. My impression was that kashrut dietary restrictions, i.e. consuming non-kosher animals, mixing meat and dairy, et al were given only to the Jewish people and therefore are not incumbent upon the rest of humanity. Is the consumption of blood an exception? All perspectives on this question are of interest to me, but I am especially curious about sources that prohibit.

Edit: The speaker in [this video](http://www.chabad.org/multimedia/media_cdo/aid/3317454/jewish/The-Baffling-Bloody-Ban.htm) (check 1:10:40) suggests that Ibn Ezra mentions this. I was wondering the extent of differing opinions on this topic  or if anyone was aware of the source.

Comment: Perhaps the reference is to Leviticus (17:10): 
וְאִ֨ישׁ אִ֜ישׁ מִבֵּ֣ית יִשְׂרָאֵ֗ל וּמִן־הַגֵּר֙ הַגָּ֣ר בְּתוֹכָ֔ם אֲשֶׁ֥ר יֹאכַ֖ל כָּל־דָּ֑ם וְנָתַתִּ֣י פָנַ֗י בַּנֶּ֙פֶשׁ֙ הָאֹכֶ֣לֶת אֶת־הַדָּ֔ם וְהִכְרַתִּ֥י אֹתָ֖הּ מִקֶּ֥רֶב עַמָּֽהּ which proscribes both the Jews and the _gerim_ residents from consuming blood. The identity of the _ger_ is debated. Many sources identify him as a full convert, others, however, tend to identify him as a non fully Jewish resident.

Answer (score 5):

Rav Yirmiyahu Kaganoff [writes](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=14572),

> Although a non-Jew may not eat the flesh of a living animal, he may
>   eat blood drawn from a living animal (Rambam, Hilchos Melachim 9:10;
>   cf. Gemara Sanhedrin 56b and 59a, and Rashi, Breishis 9:3). Some
>   African tribesmen extract blood from their livestock, mix it with
>   milk, and drink it for a nutritious beverage. Although we may consider
>   this practice very offensive, it does not violate the mitzvos of a
>   non-Jew in any way.