# Flesh from a live animal

Tags: gentiles, noachide-laws

Is flesh from a live animal permitted for a gentile to eat?  Is this included in the seven commandments?

I was unable to find this answer.

Comment: When you say flesh is that because you know a limb from a live animal is prohibited? Or you're also asking about a limb.

Comment: No I am only referring to basar min hachai

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80169/15256

Answer (score 3):

[Rambam, Hil. Melachim 9:10-11](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.9.10?lang=bi):

> וְכֵן חַיָּב עַל אֵבֶר מִן הַחַי וְעַל בָּשָׂר מִן הַחַי בְּכָל שֶׁהוּא...
>
> אֶחָד הָאֵבֶר אוֹ הַבָּשָׂר הַפּוֹרֵשׁ מִן הַבְּהֵמָה אוֹ מִן הַחַיָּה. אֲבָל הָעוֹף יֵרָאֶה לִי שֶׁאֵין בֶּן נֹחַ נֶהֱרָג עַל אֵבֶר מִן הַחַי מִמֶּנּוּ:
>
> He is liable for punishment for eating any amount of the limb of a living animal or the flesh from a living animal...
>
> The law is the same regarding a limb or flesh which separated from the animal or beast.* However, it appears to me, that a non-Jew is not executed for eating the limb of a live bird.

* I.e., whether a complete limb was detached and then a piece of flesh was separated from it, or whether the original detached piece was just flesh.

Comment: But does the goy receive any punishment for basar min hachai.  Also I think the Rambam May be a das ya hid

Comment: @Refoel חייב means that he's punishable for it. As for your claim that the Rambam is a daas yochid in this, bring some proof to that effect and then we can talk.