Is there any reason for Noahides to eat kosher
B"H
While eating kosher meat is not mentioned anywhere in the context of Noahide law, regarding the general reasoning to eat kosher, Rashi says:

These are the creatures: [The word חַיָּה, “living creature”] denotes
חַיִּים, “life.” [In the context of this passage, which sets out the
clean and unclean creatures, the meaning is expounded as follows:]
Since the Israelites cleave to the Omnipresent and are therefore
worthy of being alive, accordingly, God separated them from
uncleanness and decreed commandments upon them [so that through these
commandments Israel would live]. For the other nations, however, He
prohibited nothing. This is comparable to a physician who went to
visit a patient [who was incurable, and allowed him to eat anything he
wished, whereas when he went to his patient who was to recover, the
physician imposed restrictions on his diet that would ensure that the
recoverable patient would live. So too, the nations and Israel…], etc.
as is found in the Midrash of Rabbi Tanchuma (6).      זֹאת הַֽחַיָּה:
לְשׁוֹן חַיִּים, לְפִי שֶׁיִּשְֹרָאֵל דְּבוּקִים בַּמָּקוֹם
וּרְאוּיִין לִהְיוֹת חַיִּים, לְפִיכָךְ הִבְדִּילָם מִן הַטֻּמְאָה
וְגָזַר עֲלֵיהֶם מִצְוֹת, וְלָאֻמּוֹת לֹא אָסַר כְּלוּם, מָשָׁל
לְרוֹפֵא שֶׁנִּכְנַס לְבַקֵּר אֶת הַחוֹלֶה כּוּ' כִּדְאִיתָא
בְּמִדְרַשׁ רַבִּי תַנְחוּמָא:

It seems to imply that kosher food is beneficial for everyone, it's just that Hashem doesn't "care" about the other nations, to tell them to eat certain foods.
Would this imply that a Noahide, whom Hashem cares about more since he/she does mitzvos, also shouldn't eat no kosher food?
Obviously there's no law like this, but maybe a minhag?
Sources.

It's not that He doesn't care, it's that they don't have the spiritual sensitivity to benefit from a kosher diet. Putting premium gas in a cheap car won't make it drive any better.

I believe I heard from Rabbi Dovid Orlofsky that non-Jews benefit some s'char from any bonus mitzvah they do (beyond the 7), but not the same as a Jew. A Jew earns more from because he is obligated, which makes it more difficult to do something. In any case, for the non-Jew it really is just a bonus, no obligation whatsoever.

A Noahide is not supposed to eat living animals. Doesn't it count as a kashrut law?

Somewhat related:"Are 'things we don't do because of danger' also dangerous to non-Jews?"

@shmosel spiritual sensitivity is something people say, but the term doesn't appear in Rashi or any statement from chazal (that I know of)

@Harel13 hi. The question isn't asking about obligations, but whether it would be beneficial for them to do so

What do you think the incurable patient represents in this metaphor? Is being non-Jewish a fatal disease? Of course not. The point is they're in a condition that doesn't stand to benefit from kosher food.

@shmosel hi. It seems like the incurable disease is a metaphor for no share in the world to come. At least that's how I understood the simple meaning. But noahides, who do have a share in the world to come, might be different

@shmosel Seems that the nations are pretty spiritual to me, sometimes more so than Jews. Seems like an insult you just made to all the nations of the earth.

הרוצה לטעות יטעה

@Awtsmoos--עצמות You offered a 50 point bonus for the winning answer that answers your question before the closing the other day. My answer was posted 8 hours before closing, is the winning answer with the most votes, provides linked sources detailing answers to all the sub-questions within your main question properly. In order for you to award the 50 points to my answer, you need to check it off as the correct answer. Is there anything more you are seeking?

Noahides are following the path set by their ancestors which includes Adam and Chava.
There is a text still in existence called Sefer Raziel which contains among other things, the customs and practices of Adam after the sin and exile from the garden. That following that first Shabbat, the angel Raziel was sent to Adam to teach him how to rectify the situation that he had created.
The concept of ritually fit foods (מאכלות טהורות) was introduced to Adam and many of these practices are included in what you are describing as eating kosher. They are also found, for example, scattered in the Mishneh Torah in the section dealing with the laws of forbidden foods and in the Laws of Unfit Foods. This is not dealing with the subject of shechitah, ritual slaughter, but other aspects of kosher foods. According to most opinions, killing animals in order to eat their flesh only became available from the time of Noach. But all other aspects relating to kosher food existed from the time of Adam and Chava.
In Sefer Raziel it explains that this consumption of the ritually fit foods aids one in connecting with the Creator. Essentially, you are effected greatly in you awareness of G-d's presence by what you consume.
So yes, there are reasons that are beneficial for Noahides to follow these practices and contrary to your assumption, G-d did in fact care about all human beings and sent instruction on the preferred ways of eating via His angel Raziel.

Things changed with Noach, when more laws were introduced. Things changed with the Avot when the title "Yisrael" was restricted to their children. Did either of these changes affect the above conclusion, and if not why not, and if yes, how?

@RabbiKaii Relevant questions and something that actually is being discussed in certain quarters in Israel today in regard to being more stringent about ritually fit foods when learning certain subjects in kabbalah. For most Jews, over the millenia, people became more lax in these areas. But it is how Rambam holds. So what Adam was taught is relevant even today. The changes you mention are about meat, which was discouraged. You might find the current work by Rabbi Ohad Turgeman of interest. https://seforimcenter.com/Rabbi-Yehuda-Ohad-Turgeman-Machon-Chachmei-Yerushalayim__c-p-0-0-999.aspx

@RabbiKaii Here's another link to an interview with him that you might find of interest. https://youtu.be/svvp3EMbOP8?si=OwjAUqzhHHJNU4Ug

My answer, which was posted hours before the 8 hour closing deadline, has the highest score. By default, it is the winning answer. Why hasn’t it been awarded the 50 point bonus?

Whether it promotes physical or spiritual health it is something that all can gain from. It is just that only Jews are commanded in it.

do you have a source you can point to to support this answer, which may well be correct?

@joshwaxman see https://alhatorah.org/Purpose_of_the_Laws_of_Kashrut/2 . If you go with the last reason for the laws—separation—which is from Shadal, then perhaps the answer would be in the negative

ok, that is better, as it is a source for your statement. You can edit in these details into your answer, perhaps with bullet points, and provide some analysis based on these sources. For some of them, there is still a tiny jump, in terms of extending the reason to another group. But that is tiny. IMHO even better would be a source explicitly extending or not extending it, based on those reasons.

Genesis 9

וַיְבָ֣רֶךְ אֱלֹהִ֔ים אֶת־נֹ֖חַ וְאֶת־בָּנָ֑יו וַיֹּ֧אמֶר לָהֶ֛ם
פְּר֥וּ וּרְב֖וּ וּמִלְא֥וּ אֶת־הָאָֽרֶץ׃  God blessed Noah and his
sons, and said to them, “Be fertile and increase, and fill the earth.
וּמוֹרַאֲכֶ֤ם וְחִתְּכֶם֙ יִֽהְיֶ֔ה עַ֚ל כׇּל־חַיַּ֣ת הָאָ֔רֶץ וְעַ֖ל
כׇּל־ע֣וֹף הַשָּׁמָ֑יִם בְּכֹל֩ אֲשֶׁ֨ר תִּרְמֹ֧שׂ הָֽאֲדָמָ֛ה
וּֽבְכׇל־דְּגֵ֥י הַיָּ֖ם בְּיֶדְכֶ֥ם נִתָּֽנוּ׃  The fear and the
dread of you shall be upon all the beasts of the earth and upon all
the birds of the sky—everything with which the earth is astir—and upon
all the fish of the sea; they are given into your hand.  כׇּל־רֶ֙מֶשׂ֙
אֲשֶׁ֣ר הוּא־חַ֔י לָכֶ֥ם יִהְיֶ֖ה לְאׇכְלָ֑ה כְּיֶ֣רֶק עֵ֔שֶׂב
נָתַ֥תִּי לָכֶ֖ם אֶת־כֹּֽל׃  Every creature that lives shall be yours
to eat; as with the green grasses, I give you all these.
אַךְ־בָּשָׂ֕ר בְּנַפְשׁ֥וֹ דָמ֖וֹ לֹ֥א תֹאכֵֽלוּ׃  You must not,
however, eat flesh with its life-blood in it.  וְאַ֨ךְ אֶת־דִּמְכֶ֤ם
לְנַפְשֹֽׁתֵיכֶם֙ אֶדְרֹ֔שׁ מִיַּ֥ד כׇּל־חַיָּ֖ה אֶדְרְשֶׁ֑נּוּ
וּמִיַּ֣ד הָֽאָדָ֗ם מִיַּד֙ אִ֣ישׁ אָחִ֔יו אֶדְרֹ֖שׁ אֶת־נֶ֥פֶשׁ
הָֽאָדָֽם׃  But for your own life-blood I will require a reckoning: I
will require it of every beast; of humankind, too, will I require a
reckoning for human life, of everyone for each other!

Noahide Kashrut's basis starts in Genesis 9. Before the flood, when mankind was not allowed to eat animals, there was no fear of humans. You could walk up to an animal and it would inherently trust you according to scripture.
Once meat eating is allowed, all life will no longer trust humans. God allows every animal to be eaten by Noah's descendants, with the caveat that no animal should still be eaten with it's soul in it's blood, nor can it be eaten with blood still in it's body. Therefore, Noahides should be very strict on the treatment of animals, the slaughter of animals, and the draining of animal blood. This means every cow, pig, etc needs a kosher slaughter.
If a Noahide cannot confirm their meat follows the rules set out by God they should be a vegetarian. And it's not even just Jews who believe this, but the early Christian church set their own rules based on these ideas.
Acts 15:27-29

27 Therefore we are sending Judas and Silas to confirm by word of
mouth what we are writing. 28 It seemed good to the Holy Spirit and to
us not to burden you with anything beyond the following requirements:
29 You are to abstain from food sacrificed to idols, from blood, from
the meat of strangled animals and from sexual immorality. You will do
well to avoid these things.

According to the Jerusalem council Christians are not expected to keep ALL the laws of Moses or ALL Kashrut laws. Rather the basic minimum laws that Christians/Noahides would need to follow includes Noahide Kashrut.
They must not eat an animal that is not properly slaughtered, such as strangling an animal. This is animal cruelty and Jews and early Jewish Christians would not abide by this. Secondary to that is the understanding that there must be no eating of blood, which would include requiring the proper draining of the animal's blood.
I am unwilling to die on the hill of saying if a Noahide is offered a cup of blood he is forbidden from drinking it. But I would say that I have never seen a scripture in the Bible where God takes the consumption of blood lightly.

nice response. source for each of these? also, I think the questioner was wondering about e.g. eating pig. (btw, I wasn't the -1)

I see nothing from the Torah that wouldn't require kosher slaughter for pigs to properly drain blood from its body

so "seeing nothing", no source, is not a positive source. the way this website works is not off the cuff answers, or personal feelings. what do written Jewish sources from halachic authorities say? for instance, see this answer that sources the Rambam that Noachides may eat blood even from a living animal. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80169/are-gentiles-forbidden-from-consuming-blood Do you have a counter-source? My probing question about pigs was whether even drained pigs are prohibited for Noachides, as the comment was about "unclean creatures", e.g. non-ruminant pigs

"All of their Kashrut laws are based on this." Eating a non kosher fish doesn't involve any of those things

Where does it say that noahides can't eat blood?

I've added sources for my answers and tried to add more clarity
